# "JQuery Interface file" for Flow (Static Type Checker for JavaScript from Facebook)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, typechecking, flowtype

In Nov. 2014, 3 months ago, Facebook open-sourced a new command line tool, a static type checker called "[Flow](http://flowtype.org)".  Now I want to run it on a few of my older, existing javascript files. These contain references to the jQuery library.

My JS files were not written with static type-checking in mind.
however, after including /* @flow */ at the top of the file, when I run flow with this Command:

```
flow myfile.js
```

Result:

```
/var/www/myfilejs:70:12,17: identifier jQuery
Unknown global name
Found 1 error
```

As I understand it, the way to include jQuery into *Flow*'s type checking process is to [create an "interface file"](http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html).

Has anyone done this yet for the jQuery library? (I use jQuery 1.9)

Comment: On their [future plans page](http://flowtype.org/docs/coming-soon.html), Facebook says they intend to add "Support for converting existing TypeScript declaration files (.d.ts) for common libraries on DefinitelyTyped.org to Flow declarations." This would be a great solution, but I don't see any signs that it's happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an actual jQuery flow interface definition, you can look at the one provided in https://github.com/marudor/flowInterfaces.

Install it with:

```
npm install --save-dev iflow-jquery
```

or

```
yarn add --dev iflow-jquery
```

And then add the following to your `.flowconfig` file:

```
[libs]
node_modules/iflow-jquery/index.js.flow
```

After that, flow will infer the types of the parameters you provide to jquery functions, and will warn you if you are passing the incorrect types.

Answer (score 4):

This is my interface file I like to call `jQuery.js` in a folder I call "flow_lib". This folder can be anywhere.

This is the code the `jQuery.js` contains for the interface declaration :

```
declare module "jQuery" {
    declare function $(obj: any): any;
}

var $ = require('$').$;
```

In your `.flowconfig`, include the folder like this :

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]
<path-to-folder>/flow_lib

[options]
```

**Note** : This method does not check for actual jQuery specifications. It's just a quick fix to get rid of the flow warnings and errors related to `$` in your code. If you want to be more specific, use something like : https://github.com/solnetdigital/flow-interfaces-jquery/blob/master/interfaces/jquery.js